# Prove that if $X$ has $n$ points then $C(X,Y)$ is homeomorphic to $Y^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a finite set with $|X|=n$ equipped with the dicrete topology.Show that $C(X,Y)$ is homeomorphic to $Y^n$ where $Y^n=\overbrace{Y\times Y \times Y \cdots \times Y}^{n-times}$.

In the book there are a theorem that can help me

> Theorem:Let Let $X, Y, Z$ be spaces, and assume all function
> spaces have the compact-open topology. There exists a natural one-to-one map
> $\gamma:C((X \times Y),Z) \longrightarrow C(X,C(Y \times Z))$

Futhermore:
If $Y$ is locally compact and Hausdorff $\gamma$ is bijective.

If $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff $\gamma$ is one to one.

If $X,Y$ are both locally compact and Hausdorff $\gamma$ is homeomorphism.

The problem here is that I need have the $CO$(Compact-open) topology and I don´t have it, thus I don´t know how to apply this result to the demostration of our result.

I don´t have a idea about how to I should attack this problem.If someone may provide me a idea about how to attack the problem in this case, was useful.Thanks in advice

Comment: What topology *does* $C(X,Y)$ have? This will hold for any reasonable topology on $C(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that if $X$ has the discrete topology then $C(X,Y)$ is just the set of **all** functions from $X$ to $Y$ (every function is continuous on a discrete space).

Say, $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and we can identify the function $f: X \to Y$ with $\Phi(f)=(f(x_1), \ldots, f(x_n)) \in Y^n$, in that $\Phi$ is a bijection between these sets.

So we only need to check that $\Phi$ is open and continuous when we give the domain $C(X,Y)$ the compact-open topology (with subbasic open sets $[K,U] =\{f \in C(X,Y)\mid f[K] \subseteq U\}$, where $K \subseteq X$ is compact (but in our case **all** subsets of $X$ are finite so compact) and $U \subseteq Y$ is open.

If $\prod_{i=1}^n U_i$ is basic open in $Y^n$ (so all $U_i$ are open in $Y$)
then $$\Phi^{-1}[\prod_{i=1}^n U_i] = \{f \in C(X,Y)\mid (f(x_1), \ldots f(x_n)) \in \prod_{i=1}^n U_i\} = \bigcap_{i=1}^n [\{x_i\}, U_i]$$

and the latter is a finite intersection of subbasic open sets in C(X,Y)$, hence open.

And also if $[K, U]$ is subbasic open then $$\Phi[[K,U]]= \prod_{i = 1}^n V_i$$

where $V_i = U$ for when $x_i \in K$ and $V_i = Y$ otherwise, so $\Phi$ sends subbasic open sets to open sets and as $\Phi$ is a bijection (!) this implies $\Phi$ is an open map.

This concludes the proof that $\Phi$ is the required homeomorphism.

Comment: Note that we could also have taken the pointwise topology on $C(X,Y)$ , as it is the same in this case where $X$ is finite. If $Y$ were metric we could also have taken the uniform topology.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks a lot I can connect both answers and understand the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Compact-open on $C(A,B)$ is the usual product $B^A$ (*) if $A$ is discrete, since all maps are continuous (so they are the same underlying set) and all compacts in $A$ are finite so the subbase $[K,U]=\{f\in C(X,Y)\mid f(K)\subseteq U\}$ (over all compact $K\subseteq A$ and open $U\subseteq Y$) of compact-open can be thinned down to $[\{a\},U]$ (over all $a\in A$ and open $U\subseteq Y$), hence is the same as the subbase $\bigcap_{a\in K}\pi_a^{-1}U$ of the product topology.

(*): cheating a little in the notation here.  We are taking $B^A$ in **Sets**, and equip it with the product topology.

Comment: May explain a little bit more?, I'm new with the Compact open topology and Don't understand the notation $[K,U]$ it means $W[K,U]=\lbrace f \in C[X,Y] \mid K \subset X \rbrace$ where $K$ is compact and $U$ open of $Y$?

Comment: $[K,U]=\{f\in C(X,Y)\mid f(K)\subseteq U\}$.  Since the only compact sets are finite, we can just need to look at the subbase $[\{a\},U]$ with $a\in A$ and $U\subseteq Y$ open, which is exactly saying the set of maps that map the point $a$ to something in $Y$, i.e., $\pi_a^{-1}Y$.